# Client wants extremely badly designed website

Tags: language-agnostic

how would you handle a client who wants you to implement a website layout that looks horrible and is wrong in many many ways, when they absolutely think it is great, really "different" and cool and since you are a programmer, you don't know anything about design.

i have tried arguing, reasoning and not caring, but it pains me physically to think that i should put *that* online... any tips or experiences would be great! thanks.

update: things are even a bit more complicated, since it is not just any client but a business partner with a great business idea, that i want to be part of...

Comment: Don't put that online... you can refuse to do work. You can also deny any responsibility over it (don't put your name or anything else there)

Comment: why is this a community wiki?

Comment: because it is not a programming question...

Comment: If you don't think the client will get any customers with that design, why not suggest doing a quick & impartial focus group study to get feedback on a paper-copy of the proposed site. Better to spend a little bit on money up front than waste a lot in the longer term.

Comment: If you are getting paid to do a job...just do it. If it really is that bad then they will have to hire you again to fix it later :)

Comment: You may want to try and ask this question over at doctype as well.  While the "customer wants a bad idea" is a universal problem, they may be able to provide another perspective in addition to the good answers provided here so far.

Comment: welcome to the world of website production, every numpty thinks they know how it should look/work

Comment: I would really like to see a demo? Do you have any link we can see? :-) I guess not...

Comment: Hire a design consultant. If there's a tech twitter community local to you, you could find one quickly

Comment: I speak for everyone when I say "link please!"

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Craigslist.com is one of the most visited websites on the planet. Yet its UI is appalling by most modern aesthetics.

This isn't a technical issue, but a business issue. You need to sit down with your business partner and put forward your point of view convincingly. If you're going to work with her in the long term, then you both need to find a way of resolving issues and coming to a compromise. Look at this dispute as a warning sign about the business relationship.

Comment: amen brother! i think that might well be the core of the problem

Comment: "UI is appalling by most modern aesthetics." - Appalling but good.  User interface is more than just looks.  Sure it's UGLY, but it WORKS, proving (once again), that functional usually beats pretty.

Which I'm sure is what you meant, just clarifying :)

Comment: Pretty generally gets you in the door.  Being functional keeps you there.

Comment: @Chris - is that for dating or web sites? :-)

Comment: @Russell - it doesn't work well.  Have you ever tried looking for real estate, rentals, or appliances?  Not being able to see thumbnails makes this one of the most frustrating interfaces to search for what you need that I've ever experienced.

Answer (score 14):

He who pays the piper calls the tune.

Depends how much the coin matters.

Comment: i usually agree, but only to a certain point, which has been crossed many times over...

Comment: If you will be asked to do things wrong way again and again, however being got paid, what would you do?

Comment: if my advice fell deaf ears constantly - I'd get a new job.

Answer (score 14):

I've some experience with what you describe. I usually try to convince them their design is not as good as they think. Things like usability, navigational structure can help you in the argument. I've noticed that showing some heatmaps of how people look at websites can have a nice result. "*I never looked at it that way*"

If they however insist on the bad design, you have roughly 3 options:

1. Politely tell them to find somebody else to create the ugly site for them.
2. Make them sign a document that states that you strongly advised against the design and that they cannot hold you responsible if they get bad results or comments
3. Bow your head and build it.

Option 1 can hurt your reputation just as bad as option 3.
Option 2 sometimes convinces the client that they might be wrong after all as it is now written on an official looking piece of paper they have to sign. But a least ensures you can work with a clear conscience; you warned them, they wanted it anyway.

Good luck :)

Comment: Option 2 is clever, I've never thought of that.  +1

Comment: Option 2 is nice but I think it can hurt a relationship quite a lot.

Comment: While signing documents is not always the best option, being accused of bad work will hurt the relationship a lot more.

Answer (score 5):

Managing difficult clients is something you need to come to terms with, as a freelancer, or any sort of sufficiently experience professional.

If you don't like the design, you can have a simple thought: *Do I need this client?* If not, drop them. If you do, then just accept that you don't always get things your way, and deal with it.

If you don't want your name attached to the work, you can easily come to that compromise.

Sometimes you need to make moral choices about clients as well; in this case you just have a subjective art choice; I think it is easy enough :)

Comment: i agree 100% but what if it is a business partner, not a paying client?

Comment: Same rules apply; but there may be more money involved. I'd say if you and your partner have problems early, and you can't resolve them, you should part ways. In such a relationship, you should either leave each other to your own areas of expertise, or come to an agreement, or split up. Arguing about such things is just wasteful, when you have more important things to do when trying to launch a business.

Answer (score 4):

I have had some cases as you describe. Just keep in mind that you are creating something for your client, it's the client that will work everyday with the application and it's the client that need to be happy with it, not you :)

Comment: they won't be. it looks horribly unprofessional and they will not have a single paying customer...

Comment: being happy in terms of features is another thing. But leading the client by providing consulting of increasing the usability may increase your reputation enormously if the client notices the improvement then afterwards :)

Answer (score 4):

There have been a lot of answers that boil down to:

- Just do it for the $$$
- Do a mock up of something better
- Run a usability test
- Run like hell (but politely)

All of these assume that:

1. The design really is bad
2. You are objectivly approaching this project

**Please don't hear what I'm not saying: I am not saying your premise is wrong.**

First, I am saying its worth considering that it may not be that bad. There are a lot of very successful sites out there that drive designers nuts. If it doesn't satisfy a need, it won't matter how well its done.

If you want to be a part of this than you need to look at the business plan first, and see if its valid, and if the site will fulfill it. If either one of those is a no-go, than fix those problems first.

Second, ask your associate if (s)he's considered other designs. Ask for the sites they used to come up with what they want, and ask what else they've considered.

If they give you something, look at what makes those good/bad and see if between the two of you you can come to a better design.

If they can't, then tell them that with some work there may be something better and work together to create 3 or 4 mock ups. *Then* whip out the usabilty test. Even if you've done them before, I highly recommend reading what Jakob Nielsen has to say about it over at http://www.useit.com/alertbox/

Since this seems to be a business partner, just doing it for the money and/or running like hell doesn't seem to be an option. Working through this with a little more give and take may help, but if you can't come to an agreement, then you probably ought to leave.

Comment: +1 for the nice summary. and yes, 1+2 are true. if it were a client i'd take the money and run...

Answer (score 3):

### Ask users that match targeted audience

Why don't you create a mockup of a particular part of this app/site and try asking a few people that represent the persona of the product. The targeted audience. Give them two possible choices and let users decide what will make business value instead of you or the client.

Answer (score 2):

Be careful since the first thing I would do when coming to such a website is to look who's the webmaster that produced that site. And then if I would see your logo below it wouldn't impress me. It's not for your good reputation.

So as a professional in that area, I would try to discuss the design with your client, offering him your knowledge about good website design, since that may be also part of the service you're offering.

Comment: well there are always the difficult ones and the others :)

Answer (score 2):

If you really need the money, just do what he wants and take the cash. Avoid your name appearing on the site anywhere.

If you have other work lined up, tell the client you think he would be better off with a different designer that can meet his needs and say goodbye.

My experience of this kind of client tells me they are a royal pain the arse, with endless tweaks and adjustments to the design. Get out while you can.

Comment: i agree 100% but what if it is a business partner, not a paying client?

Answer (score 2):

Do it. In your own time do your own version - as you want it to be great, which you do as you have a stake in it (you want to be part of it). Show them the better idea. Make them buy into it by making them feel part of it, not that you have done it behind thier back. *the idea just came to me and I done it*. If they don't like it tough – you could never have won. However they might just be impressed at your effort and/or initiative.

Comment: hmm, interesting. i have actually done a "normal" version which was deemed boring, because it's "too normal". also, i am no designer...

Answer (score 1):

I'd say do it but put nothing identifying you or your company on it, and keep it the hell away from your portfolio. Also have very explicit conditions around ongoing support for it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could bring in a third party, someone whose opinion on design and suggestions for improvement your business partner would respect -- maybe a graphic designer or a web usability expert. That way, you might be able to salvage this business opportunity without alienating your business partner.

Comment: well, get this: it comes from a designer! a really bad one.

Comment: Still... a colleague might have more sway with your business partner than you, the supposedly design-insensitive programmer...

Answer (score 1):

I agree with others. If you don't need the work than politely decline. If you do, release what the client wants and make them pay for every tweak after launch once they realise the design sucks.

Answer (score 1):

Perform usability tests. Create a mockup that's fairly close and get people involved from the target audience. If they are a designer then they should understand that this is a sensible approach. Be careful to introduce it as best in both your interests.

The key is to get independent feedback. That keeps you sweet with your business partner and you also get a good design.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a bad design and it's being pushed, then it's someone's "baby" and you can't touch it.

It won't matter how good your alternative is.  It won't matter if you can point to the exact same site in, "Web Pages that Suck."  It won't matter if senior executives quietly say, "Wow - I really like the alternative - it makes us look Fortune 500!"  It won't matter if you bring surveys, focus groups, or if Jesus, Himself, shines the light of truth on your alternative and blesses it: you'll be branded as a, "non-team player," and the cruddy site will STILL be posted.

Then, in 18 months, after you're gone and the three people who were hired to replace you EVENTUALLY cough up a site with minor, almost embarrassing, changes that actually make the site resemble an ad for adult incontinence products, you can come back to this post and say, "Hey - thanks.  You... were right."

Comment: If you really want to understand why this is, read, "The Fountainhead."  Mediocrity exists, and is actually fought for, for a specific reason: mediocrity can be controlled; high performers, individualists cannot.

Answer (score 0):

I want to add an Link to my question:

[Storing Password in Databases in plain text vs Customer Needs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193697/storing-password-in-databases-in-plain-text-vs-customer-needs)

In some cases it is the same issue. There are customer needs that are not acceptable. the answer provided in that question maybe help you find a way around that problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've worked with this person before, when a university website was being designed by committee.  We had two people come up with designs, and the initial vote went 12 to 1 ... the one who was ahead was done by a professor of commercial art, who couldn't care less if you didn't like his design.  The other one, though ... she had to come out and defend every little aspect of her design.  The revote was 1 to 12, as I refused to change my vote.

Luckily, three of the people from the graphics department came up with a new design, and presented it at the next meeting, and everyone agreed it was better, so we were able to torpedo the blinking splash screen and George Washington's hair design.

Anyway, the point is -- you have to find out why she prefers her design, and then come up with something that takes each of those points, but doesn't suck.  Unfortunately, it might take someone with design experience to manage to put it all together -- but if you're planning this to be a business venture, it might be worth spending some money on.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my suggestions:

1. Why is the design bad?  Make sure you understand why before you get into this conversation.  Remember, there is some business goal behind having a website.  Understand that, and use it as your point.  If you don't know what the goal is, ask.  If they don't know what the goal is, help them figure it out.
2. Offer alternatives.  Point out the positives and negatives, and help them understand what the tradeoffs are.
3. Mockups and tests.  If you can, mock up the alternative, and let them see the differences.  Get potential users to try them out if possible.  If not, at least have the customer use the mocked-up website *as an actual customer,* trying to fulfill an *actual scenario.*

Good design is the design that will meet the stated business goals of the customer (assuming that this is a business website).

Also, understand what your job is.  Is your job to help them solve a business problem, or to implement a specific solution they have in mind?  Understanding their expectations of you may help significantly.