# Simple sql wont work

Tags: sql

Hello im having a bit of a problem, look at this:

```
SELECT id, activate_key FROM accounts
WHERE id = $accNum 
AND password = '$password' AND activate_key = NULL
// Success! the id and password matched and the activate_key field is null
```

This is my login.
As Soon as I add `AND activate_key = NULL` you cant login on any account, even if the activate_key field is NULL.

Sorry for the title, as im not a sql guru i couldnt think of a better title explaining my problem

Comment: Also should not be [storing passwords in plain text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193697/storing-password-in-databases-in-plain-text-vs-customer-needs).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `IS NULL`. `=` won't work with NULL.

[edit]

Don't forget to escape your password! Your query will fail and can potentially harm your database if you don't.

Answer (score 0):

Try

`activate_key IS NULL`

instead of

```
activate_key = NULL
```